# How to convert between camelCase PascalCase snake_case kebab-case (JS)

Tags: javascript

Maybe someone will find it useful - How to convert between camelCase PascalCase snake_case kebab-case (JS)

Answer (score 0):

```
'use strict'

const log = console.log.bind(console);

const toCamel = val => val.trim().replace(/([-_ ]+)./g, $ => $.at(-1).toUpperCase());
const toKebab = val => toCamel(val).replace(/[A-Z]+(?![a-z])|[A-Z]/g, ($, o) => (o ? "-" : "") + $.toLowerCase())
const toSnake = val => toCamel(val).replace(/[A-Z]+(?![a-z])|[A-Z]/g, ($, o) => (o ? "_" : "") + $.toLowerCase())
const toPascal = val => toCamel(val).replace(/^./, $ => $.toUpperCase());

const testCase = [
    'StackOverflow',
    'camelCase',
    'alllowercase',
    'JSONdata',
    '         aaa--------bbb-ccc',
    'aaa_______bbb__ccc_dddddddddd',
    'aaa          bbb -ccc',
    'ddd-eee-fff',
];

log(testCase.map(toCamel));
```

Comment: This has some issues, e.g. imho, `_myPrivateIdentifier` is valid camel-case.

Comment: i wrote this becouse maybe it help someone, please fill free to modify that code to Your needs, in my case it is good enough,

Comment: (also e.g. "StackOverflow" is pascal-case, but `camelCase` doesn't change it to camel-case)

Comment: and in modern JS, in class there are #privateProperty or #privateMethod()

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash package.

```
      _.kebabCase('Foo Bar');
    // => 'foo-bar'

    _.snakeCase('Foo Bar');
    // => 'foo_bar'


 startCase(camelCase(str)).replace(/ /g, '');
```

Comment: but this is VanillaJS solution - no liblary needed

Comment: your solution you mean ?
Yes I know it is vanillaJS but some developers prefer reducing lines. and prefer to use tested library such as Lodash

Comment: hymmmm @mohammed-naji i'm curious where U can see jQuery in this solution?